# Entity version in odata using accept header in web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, odata, asp.net-web-api

I am using Web API to create RESTful services.  I decided to using Accept header as a api versioning mechanism by following this implementation.
 http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2013/03/08/Custom-media-types-for-ASPNET-Web-API-versioning.aspx

Accept: application/json; version=1

For entity standardization and query capabilities, I planned to use Odata.  The problem currently I see is that the odata only supports(or only I know) the entity versioning using url.

```
 modelBuilder1.EntitySet<V1.Product>("Products");
 modelBuilder2.EntitySet<V2.Product>("Products");

 Microsoft.Data.Edm.IEdmModel model1 = modelBuilder1.GetEdmModel();
 Microsoft.Data.Edm.IEdmModel model2 = modelBuilder2.GetEdmModel();

 config.Routes.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute1", "api\v1", model1);
 config.Routes.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute2", "api\v2", model2);
```

Is there any solution available for to configure odata to consider accept header ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Entityset names cannot have / in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a very good sample on versioning using web API OData. You can find it [here](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/ODataVersioningSample/ReadMe.txt)

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the solution and it looks promisisng.  I will validate and update this thread.  In meantime I like to keep this thread open for others answers.

Comment: I am finding a problem in the controller selector provided in the sample solution. When I tried using the version in header.  The controller always selects the first registered route.  So I am alwyas ending up to the first registered version of the controller.

Comment: @raghuram-nadiminti - I was very happy to find the example and initially it worked great.  However, because of the mapping of the ViewModel to the Db Entity, $expand doesn't seem to work. Each version's $metadata shows the navigation properties, they just don't work.  Do you know, is it possible to get this working?